# Max RCI zones in SimCity Deluxe, unable to delete a zone

Tags: simcity-deluxe

I have maxed out my RCI zones, and am unable to re-zone on top of a demolished zone because I've "run out'

How do I delete a zone to nothing?  Or how do I get past the pop-up in the case where I'm trying to rezone an existing zone?

This is Sim City Deluxe for Blackberry, one of the many apps that are being given away for free on the Blackberry App World through the end of this month.

Comment: Is there not a de-zoning tool in the game? That's how you would do it on SC2k and up on PC.

Comment: Not one I see for Blackberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work around it. Build something on top of the zones you want to change. Then demolish the buildings and re-zone. Slow and painful, but it will get you there eventually. You might have to cover quite a bit of ground before you get rid of the max RCI pop-up.